# Showing the data of two rows into one row

Tags: oracle, transpose

I have a table with data as

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CUSTOMER    CSAC        CIRCUIT              VALUE       TOWN       POST_CODE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RCE |   CSAC125896 |    ICUK809605 |    100 MBPS |  BASILDON |  SS15 5FS
    RCE |   CSAC125896 |    ICUK809605 |    100 MBPS |  BASILDON |  SS15 6AA
```

I want the second post code also to be displayed in the same row if the csac values are same like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CUSTOMER  CSAC   CIRCUIT    VALUE        TOWN       POST_CODE   POST_CODE2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
RCE|CSAC125896 |ICUK809605 |100 MBPS |  BASILDON |  SS15 5FS |  SS15 6AA
```

How can I achieve this result. I have tried using transpose but didn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER,
       CSAC,
       CIRCUIT,
       VALUE,
       TOWN,
       MAX( CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN POST_CODE END ) AS POST_CODE_1,
       MAX( CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN POST_CODE END ) AS POST_CODE_2
FROM   (
  SELECT  t.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CUSTOMER, CSAC, CIRCUIT, VALUE, TOWN
            ORDER BY POST_CODE
          ) AS RN
  FROM    table_name t
)
GROUP BY  CUSTOMER,
          CSAC,
          CIRCUIT,
          VALUE,
          TOWN;
```

**Output**:

```
CUSTOMER CSAC       CIRCUIT    VALUE    TOWN     POST_CODE_1 POST_CODE_2
-------- ---------- ---------- -------- -------- ----------- -----------
RCE      CSAC125896 ICUK809605 100 MBPS BASILDON SS15 5FS    SS15 6AA
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can have more than two rows with the same field values, but different POST_CODE, you can not know in advance the number of columns your query needs to return.

With a slightly different approach, you can try:

```
select CUSTOMER, CSAC, CIRCUIT, VALUE, TOWN,
       listagg(POST_CODE, ', ') within group (order by post_code)
from your_table
group by CUSTOMER, CSAC, CIRCUIT, VALUE, TOWN
```